# Do I have to list all the columns in order and have values for each one in INSERT statement?

Tags: mysql, insert

Is this possible or do I have to list all the columns?

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, **column3**, column2,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Do I have to list all the columns in order and have values for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your INSERT statement it should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column3, column2,...) VALUES (value1, value3, value2,...)
```

Since you moved column3, value3 should "match up" with it

Answer (score 5):

You only have to put the columns you plan on inserting. The only order that needs to match up is the column name and value.

IE: 3 Columns: `col1`, `col2`,`col3`

`INSERT INTO TABLE (`col1`,`col2`) VALUES(`col1value`,`col2value`)`

`INSERT INTO TABLE (`col2`,`col3`) VALUES(`col2value`,`col3value`)`

`INSERT INTO TABLE (`col3`,`col2`) VALUES(`col3value`,`col2value`)`

Answer (score 1):

You can put your query columns in any order, as long as you specify that order like you are doing above.  The actual values you insert as part of the `VALUE` clause must match the `INSERT INTO (x,y,z)` part of your query.

Any columns that you do *not* specify will have a default value inserted.  The default value is determined by the `DEFAULT` value set when the column was created.

Your `INSERT` can fail if a column has a `NOT NULL` specification on it and no `DEFAULT` value, and you do not provide one in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your column names must correspond to the values that you are inserting.  For instance, in your above query, if column1 is a varchar, column3 an int, etc, the values must correspond and be in the exact order for your query to execute successfully.